# Run one query inside another phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am new to SQL's and phpmyadmin so I apologize if this is unclear. I am trying to use a query as a data source from a different query but I am getting a parsing error from SELECT. Here is what I am trying to do.

```
select CUS_CODE,
    COUNT(LINE.INV_NUMBER) as "Number of Invoices",
    AVG("Invoice Total") as "Average Invoice Amount",
    MAX("Invoice Total") as "Max Invoice Amount",
    MIN("Invoice Total") as "Min Invoice Amount",
    Sum("Invoice Total") as "Total Customer Purchases"
from (
    select CUS_CODE,
        LINE.INV_NUMBER as INV_NUMBER,
        Sum(LINE.LINE_UNITS * LINE.LINE_PRICE) as "Invoice Total"
    from INVOICE,
        LINE
    where INVOICE.INV_NUMBER = LINE.INV_NUMBER
    group by CUS_CODE,
        LINE.INV_NUMBER
    )
group by CUS_CODE;
```

Comment: @GurV still getting the same error - parsing error at SELECT

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select cus_code,
    count(inv_number) as number_of_invoices,
    avg(invoice_total) as average_invoice_amount,
    max(invoice_total) as max_invoice_amount,
    min(invoice_total) as min_invoice_amount,
    sum(invoice_total) as total_customer_purchases
from (
    select cus_code,
        l.inv_number,
        sum(l.line_units * l.line_price) as invoice_total
    from invoice i
    join line l on i.inv_number = l.inv_number
    group by cus_code,
        l.inv_number
    ) t
group by cus_code;
```

Few comments:

- Use modern explicit join syntax instead of old comma based one.
- Use alias for subquery
- `LINE.INV_NUMBER` is not valid outside subquery. Directly use `INV_NUMBER`
- Don't use non standard aliases. Instead of using space and backticks, use underscore `_`

Comment: @RyanB - Updated just now. Please try now?

Comment: @RyanB - Can you emulate the error on http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler and share the link here?

Comment: @RyanB - Please include table DDLs in the demo too. At present some othe table are present in there and none of them as cus_code present.